# Network Storage Bash

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, network-shares

I was wondering how to connect to a network storage through the command line on my MacOSX computer, any tips?

Comment: A mounted directory or other network service?  Please describe.

Comment: It's a network service, my school provides 2gb of storage and I would like to write a script that connects to it.

Comment: We need more information on what kind of 'network storage' is being provided, and what interface is required to use it.

Comment: I guess I don't really know sorry

Answer (score 1):

As said before it depends on sharing protocols.

You can connect to a server (while in Finder) with :

Cmd + k

You have to find out which protocol is used for sharing ... (smb, afp, ...) !

My first guess will be : smb (samba)

In the Server Address field enter:

```
smb://serverhostname.domain/pathtoyourhomefolder
```

Save it to your Favorite Server list (+ button)

Then hit Connect, your remote folder will automatically be mounted on your Desktop.

About command line (if the sharing is SMB) : `man smbclient` is your friend

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to mount a file system you should use one of the mount_* commands.

As an example, I have a script that periodically mounts a SMB volume, copies some files and then unmounts:

```
mkdir /Volumes/[mountpoint]
mount_smbfs //[username]:[password]@[hostname]/[sharename] /Volumes/[mountpoint]
... copy some files ...
umount /Volumes/[mountpoint]
```

This assumes you have permissions to create a directory in /Volumes. Any directory will do, really - you just need write permissions.

The URL for a mount point on a remote server if different for each protocol, check the particular man pages for more info.

In general, you need to create the mount point first using mkdir, but umount will delete it afterwards.

Comment: in linux *smbfs* and *cifs* are similar means to the same end; use *cifs* (eg *mount_cifs*) if available.